# How get the title from php?

Tags: php, html

I know english a little bit, I'm using this service first time.

Ans so I have this code:

```
    if($curl = curl_init()){
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, "http://diesel.elcat.kg/index.php?showtopic=134877653");
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
            $out = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);

            $tmp = substr($out,strpos($out,'<title>'),56);
            var_dump($tmp);
        }
```

This code gets the html code:

```
"string '<title>Как дальше двигаться php? - Diesel Forum</title>
' (length=56)"
```

I need other code, only title without strings and length.

Comment: The `string` and `length` part just originate from the `var_dump()` call. If you had used `echo`, you would not have seen them.

Comment: Where is the code where you want to add this "title" ? your title is well written in your `$tmp` variable, so where do you want to use it ? the problem you notice is only due to `var_dump`, not to the content of `$tmp`...

Answer (score 0):

I say you use echo and just do something like `<?php echo $title; ?>` and then specify title elsewhere where it's needed, like `<?php $title = "<title>"; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

[var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) displays full informations about the variable, use [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) instead

```
    if($curl = curl_init()){
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, "http://diesel.elcat.kg/index.php?showtopic=134877653");
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        $out = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        $tmp = substr($out,strpos($out,'<title>'),56);
        echo($tmp);
    }
```

Comment: @HeartOfprogrammer try using `echo $tmp;`

Comment: just don't have nothing to

Comment: echo displays it on the current generated page... if you see nothing, maybe you don't look at the right place... what do you want to do with this title ? where do you want it to be printed ?

Comment: I want that code will take title from website - "http://diesel.elcat.kg/index.php?showtopic=134877653" and print in my page. My website is staying in localhost